# How do I Set Parent to Armature?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, parent

So I actually had this working, and without changing anything (or so I thought) it stopped working, and the error I get is just a "this won't work" without even pointing me to a line or anything.  Here's the code:

```
import bpy

#Set parent
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

ob= bpy.data.objects['Tuxedo Shirt']
arma = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
arma.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arma 

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

parent_bone = 'CC_Base_BoneRoot' # choose the bone name which you want to be the parent

arma.data.edit_bones.active = arma.data.edit_bones[parent_bone]

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all objects
ob.select = True
arma.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arma    #the active object will be the parent of all selected object

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='BONE', keep_transform=True)
```

I know there are redundancies there, but it was how the code got built and I didn't want to alter anything from what was working.  And, yes, those are the right names of the mesh and bone (like I said, it was working just fine -- obviously I must have changed *something* but I have no idea what it was).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working, but I'm still not quite sure why it works now.  I started by getting rid of all the extraneous crap but where it was crapping out *seemed* to be at the bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') statement, which still seems to me to be harmless.  Anyway, here's the code that works:

```
import bpy

#deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

ob= bpy.data.objects['Tuxedo Shirt']
arma = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
arma.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arma 

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

parent_bone = 'CC_Base_BoneRoot' # choose the bone name which you want to be the parent

arma.data.edit_bones.active = arma.data.edit_bones[parent_bone]

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all objects
ob.select = True
arma.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arma    #the active object will be the parent of all selected object

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='BONE', keep_transform=True)
```

I kind of hate it when it looks like magic and I don't understand why, but at least I'm not going to worry about it for now (if anyone has an explanation for it, though, I'd love to hear).